# Is it possible to use an external keyboard with SceneKit on iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

Title says it all. We want to add arrow key and WASD key support in our SceneKit app on iOS but I'm not sure how to set the view up to respond to keyboard events without a UITextView, which obviously doesn't apply here.

Comment: I disagree with your critique. I am asking about its use with SceneKit which yes, may technically mean without a UITextView or the like, but how do I know there's not some other API that's part of SceneKit or GameKit or the like dedicated to keyboard input the same way there's game controller APIs? You know that because I see you've written a book on it, but I'm new to it and have that question. Plus, in good SO citizenship, my question is something that people may want to search on--its intent--so while technically you are correct, I stand by my question as posed.

Comment: Also, your unnecessary comment aside, I have to admit your book looks interesting. While I am not a fan of people peddling their wares here on SO (link to your site is fine, then sell it there, but you shouldn't advertise it here directly) it does seem to be a quality product. I'm considering pulling the trigger on it. Question... are updates as you add more going to be free?